# XMLHttpRequest attributes are empty when called directly

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am uploading files over a form and XMLHttpRequest to my server. The relevant code I am using to do this is as follows.

```
async function POST_upload (html_form_id, url) {
    const form = document.getElementById(html_form_id);
    const multiple_files = form.querySelector("input[type=file]");

    if (multiple_files.files.length) {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        const formData = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
            multiple_files.files,
            function (formData, file) {
                formData.append(multiple_files.name, file);
                return formData;
            },
            new FormData()
        );

        request.open("POST", url);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        request.upload.addEventListener(
        "progress",
        function(event) {
            /* Progress happened. */
        },
        false);

        request.upload.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function(event) {
            /*
                Upload completed successfully.
            */

            console.log(request);
            console.log(request.readyState);
            console.log(request.response);
            console.log(request.responseText);
        },
        false);

        request.upload.addEventListener(
        "loadend",
        function(event) {
            /*
                Upload completed.
                Alway triggers, no matter if the upload was successful or not.
            */
        },
        false);

        request.upload.addEventListener(
        "abort",
        function(event) {
            /*
                Upload was aborted by user.
            */
        },
        false);

        request.upload.addEventListener(
        "error",
        function(event) {
            /*
                Upload was aborted by an error.
            */
        },
        false);

        request.send(formData);
    }
};

document.getElementById("upload_form").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    POST_upload("upload_form", "/weather/ajax/upload/");
});
```

The upload works fine and the response I am getting is a JSON formatted string with details to the file I just uploaded.

[image]

When I am now trying to read the **request** object in the **load** event and print it to the console, everything shows up as expected. As you can see in the **green box**, all attributes are filled with the correct information.

However, if I then try to print the **readyState**, **response** or **responseText** of that request-object to the console (**red boxes**), the readyState suddenly changed from 4 to 1 and both response and responseText are empty.

[image]

I had the suspicion that maybe the content of the object somehow changes between me reading the object and it's attributes, so I added another **console.log(request)** after **console.log(request.responseText)**, but there the attributes were there again.

So my question is... why can't I seem to access the attributes of the request-object here? This seems kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was that the end of the upload is not the end of the request. I listened to the wrong event.

Changing **request.*upload*.addEventListener("load", ...)** to **request.addEventListener("load", ...)** fixed the issue.